# How can I install keyboard for android 4.0.4 on android 5.1.1?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, keyboard, installation, 5.1-lollipop, apk

My phone with android 4.0.4 is rooted and I got the SamsungIME apk and odex files, moved them to the phone with android 5.1.1, but when I try to install, it simply says "App not installed". I didn't expect it to be so simple...

I've searched everywhere, but I know both phones are too old and any forum or link I found was dead. But hey, I'm old school

I can see the apk's information but I guess it's in "machine language" because it just looks like letters and symbols. I wouldn't know what to do with it anyway

Here's some info if it's of any help:

- The phone from which I want to get the keyboard is a Galaxy Pocket, android version 4.0.4 Ice Cream Sandwich, kernel version 3.0.15-1222370, keyboard version 1.0
- The phone to where I want to move the keyboard is a Galaxy J1 Ace, android version 5.1.1 Lollipop, kernel version 3.10.65-12300964, keyboard version 4.0

If you need any more information, of course let me know, and thanks in avance, if you can figure it out I'll buy you an ice cream

Comment: you need to deodex it

Comment: https://theground.jimdofree.com/android/was-ist-odex-deodex-erklärung